# How to invert camera/controls for Unity Android VR App?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope, google-cardboard

I have a fresh project in Unity with the Google Cardboard SDK imported. Default orientation is set to Landscape Right.

Whenever I load up the build on my Android device, everything is upside down. Also, if I look left in real life, it turns my head right on the phone, and vice versa. The camera and controls seem to be inverted.

I've somewhat fixed the camera problem by rotating it 180 degrees. Great. But, my controls are still inverted.

**What I need to know is how to invert controls on Unity**. *Or some way to fix this problem.*

Comment: That's a strange question to ask about your own code that implements said control when we don't even have a chance to look at it.

Comment: Are you using Unity 4 Free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the SDK v0.4.10. Check out the [repo issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/29).
You can either downgrade to the [v0.4.9](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/releases) or upgrade to Unity 5. I suggest both.

Comment: can you share any link to support this?

Comment: [Camera Upside Down Issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/29) I spent a whole weekend trying to fix it and found out there was a bug.